# Unresolved reference: CALL_PHONE No logro resolver este problema

Tags: kotlin

Llevo horas tratando de solucionar el error **Unresolved reference: CALL_PHONE** pero no tengo éxito. He eliminado cache, he reconstruido el proyecto. Lo he revisado de arriba abajo y no hayo la solucion.

Este es mi MainActivity.kt:

```
 package com.example.misaldo




import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.example.misaldo.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.example.misaldo.ui.theme.MiSaldoTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {


    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

      binding.llamada.setOnClickListener { requestPermission() }

    }

    private fun requestPermission() {
       if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){



           when{
               ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                   this,
                   Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE
               ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> {
                   call()
               }
               else -> requestpermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)

           }
       }else{

           call()

       }


    }

    private fun call() {

        startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:*222#")))
    }


    private val requestpermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
    ){isGranted->

        if(isGranted){
            call()

        }else{

            Toast.makeText(, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }

    }

}
```

Y este es mi Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MiSaldo"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MiSaldo">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Buen día, no estropees tu publicación agregando letras sin sentido para cubrir la cantidad de texto que requiere [es.so], en lugar de eso puedes escribir lo que has intentado para que las respuestas que recibas no ofrezcan cosas que ya has intentado y descartado como solución.